# how to plot ~~200k of data pairs on a 2D chart ? Is it possible with php?

Tags: math, statistics, charts

i have a csv file with data like this:

```
-0.0889 4.53
-0.0449 2.25
-0.013 -3
0.0304 -4.28
0.0669 -2.03
0.1332 -1.72
```

And it goes on and on. I need a solution to plot it as a not connected points on simple 2D chart and save it as png file to see if data is organized by a clearly visible pattern.

Comment: Have made any attempt? What part of the problem do you need help with?

Comment: Does it have to be pure PHP? What about running this through graphviz?

Comment: No, I never tried to find solution myself as I never have experienced anything with graphs. Now I must learn alot, but thanks for graphviz, I never heard before about it.

Comment: Update: I played with graphmatica with this, this program has options to plot tables of 2d data on screen and also has ability to match a function that tries to represent this data but is also awfully slow in doing it when it deals with a lot of data.

Answer (score 3):

Use the right tool for the job: [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you into the right timescale, here is a timed graph done with Mathematica.

200K points in .1 sec

[image]

HTH!